# perl-cgi script slowness

Tags: perl

I have a perl-cgi script which is log to cisco devices and run a command. so recently move the script from old solaris server to the newer more powerful vm server. now the script is very slow to log to the device actually got timeout. I am not expert on perl and I don't know how I can troubleshoot.regarding of the network there is no issue detected upon my test. as I said the server and the network at least 10 x faster than the old one. any suggestion? thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script was probably written using blocking sockets. The fact that it moved has probably slowed down the connection between the cisco devices and the server running the CGI. I would check your network path first. If this is still a concern you should write this to fork() a child process, use non-blocking socket techniques or write a CLI app. This doesn't sound like something that is well suited to run as a CGI.

Comment: thanks, I will check the path. may be the new server is a virtual server while the old one is a physical server that may add additional path.